# Can you catch a thrown error down the line?

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller, exception

I'm trying to setup a method to make sure all the data I need is available before proceeding to the next part of my component. So I have something like this:

```
public Boolean getIsDataLoaded(){
    /* loop through possible data points */
    for(Integer i : params.keySet()){
        try{
            /* Attempt to get the data for this parameter */
            String p = getParam(i); // Which then uses getValue(i)
        } catch(CustomException e){
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

This loop causes each parameter to be run through the `getValue()` method. This method then uses a parser method from another class which will throw custom exceptions. Previously I was able to run each one of these steps using a throw/catch every step of the way.

I want to know now, can I just have the **one** catch I have here instead of one at each level up abstraction passing it "down the line". I was under the impression that as long as someone caught it then I wouldn't get the Salesforce error page.

Comment: Why don't you put the whole `for` loop into a `try` block?

Comment: Tried that too, didn't work so that's why I thought I was doing something wrong to not `catch` it soon enough

Comment: When you say 'every step of the way', do you mean for each item in the loop, or within each layer of abstraction in the code?  i.e. Are you essentially asking whether your getValue() method can just not handle the exception from the parser, then let higher up methods handle it?

Comment: @NickCook this is correct, per each layer of abstraction, hoping to not include in `getValue()` or others

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your `getIsDataLoaded()` method is just returning a yes or no, couldn't you do something like:

```
public Boolean getIsDataLoaded(){
    Boolean isLoaded = true;
    /* loop through possible data points */
    for(Integer i : params.keySet()){
        try{
            /* Attempt to get the data for this parameter */
            String p = getParam(i); // Which then uses getValue(i)
        } catch(CustomException e){
            isLoaded = false;
        }
    }

    return isLoaded;
}
```

You're essentially testing with the `String p = getParam(i);` and if that passes the data must be loaded.  You keep a current state of whether the data is loaded in `isLoaded` and if all parameters pass, you return true.

Either way, it doesn't matter where the exception is thrown, you just need to ensure it's caught in some way.

For example, if you want to display detailed information about what failed, you'd want to capture the exception and (assuming this is on a VF page) you can add it to a pageMessages component.

Not sure if this is what you're after though.

Comment: I like that addition, but the `CustomException` is still not getting caught, so the page is displaying a salesforce override error screen

Comment: Are you sure it's the CustomException that's not being caught, and not a generic exception?  you can always change the CustomException to just Exception.

Comment: I changed to `Exception` and that did not work. I removed the `throw new CustomException` and the error went away... I think I just need to clean up some of my methods at this point it could be an oversite

Comment: I'd suggest the simplified version of your code is missing something then.  If getParam() or any method it calls is throwing an exception, the defined try/catch block will catch it.  By definition, you're throwing a CustomException so it must be catchable, especially seeing as you're receiving an error on the page.

Comment: Catching generic `Exceptions` is... a bad code smell at best. I like to call them a `pokemon catch`. Gotta catch 'em all! You should know what type of exception you are looking for in *almost* every scenario.